# How can I retrieve the AdMob AppID value from AndroidManifest.xml using REST API in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I want to provide the AdMob AppID value, which we added to the AndroidManifest.xml, within the application using a REST API.

There should be a way to change the AdMob AppID, just like we can change the app icon and name in the AndroidManifest.xml.

I couldn't find any examples or resources.

Comment: `xml` resources are immutable.